# Post-hoc pairwise

Tags: r, survival

I'm trying to conduct a post-hoc (multiple comparison) analysis on the data (`bmt`), (`KMsurv`) and focusing on the variables `t2` and `d3` only.

Here is the code used:

```
library(KMsurv)
data(bmt)
bmt
library(survival)

# run the ANOVA and print out the ANOVA table:
anova1 <- aov( (t2,d3) ~ group, data = bmt )
summary(anova1)


TukeyHSD(anova1)
```

I got this error message:
Error in TukeyHSD.aov(anova1) : no factors in the fitted model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: t2
2: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: d3

I have installed the package `multcomp` but I'm not sure if this package is necessary.

How can I fix that error?

Comment: your formula in `aov` contains a syntax error: anything like `(1, 2)` will give that error

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: i'm not sure what model you are trying to get, the `aov` formula should look like `y ~ v1 + v2 + ...`

Comment: There is no T2 or D3 column in the `bmt` dataset just as there is no `group` column in the `burn` dataset. So your formula is attempting to test for the association of variables in two different and unrelated datasets. So your question is incoherent on several levels. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I meant to write (bmt) instead of (burn)